# IIS allowing routing to virtual dir

Tags: angular, azure, iis, web-config

I'm trying to host my angular app and api in the same Web App on Azure.
but I'm having some difficulties accessing my api.

the folder structure is as following:

```
├───api
│   └───bin
│   └───web.config <== API web.config
├───index.html
├───web.config <== Angular web.config
├───...
└───assets
    ├───flags
    ├───i18n
    ├───icons
    └───images
```

So I need to tell my Angular `web.config` to redirect all `/api` calls to the api. while still reverting all other calls to the `index.html` in the root folder

but I can't seem to get it right, this is my current web.config. But this redirects my api calls to the client's index.html.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
        <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
        <remove fileExtension=".ttf" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="font/woff" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="font/ttf" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".webmanifest" mimeType="application/manifest+json" />
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="1.00:00:00" />
    </staticContent>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="." />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
   <!-- gzip compression -->
    <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
      <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" staticCompressionLevel="9" />
      <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="font/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
      </dynamicTypes>
      <staticTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="font/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
      </staticTypes>
    </httpCompression>
    <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
  </system.webServer>

   <location path="index.html">
      <system.webServer>
          <staticContent>
            <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" />
          </staticContent>
      </system.webServer>
    </location>

    <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This results in following checklist

- loads angular app => **TRUE**
- loads files (favicon, main.js, ngsw-worker.js) => **TRUE**
- loads manifest.webmanifest => **TRUE**
- loads api => **FALSE**

anybody got an idea of a working `web.config`?

*UPDATE*: Fixed manifest.webmanifest issue by adding it to the staticcontent

Comment: any error messages?

Comment: this redirects my api calls to the client's index.html. (added to question)

Comment: I have this same setup. You might need to add a <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false"> node to your web.config for the angular app. This would go as a direct child of the <configuration /> node.

Comment: @Sage tried doing this, but I might need some more info on where and how to place this, it seems like it doesn't work. but what I can find on the internet isn't really helping me

Comment: try this: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
 <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
  <system.webServer>
<!-- Rest of your web.config -->

Comment: also, I assume your Angular app is coded to make requests to "/api/[endpoint]", right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188122/discussion-between-sage-and-kiwi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this same setup running in Azure App Services and also ran in to issues trying to get everything to work correctly. In the end, the issue I had was with my SPA Apps web.config was being inherited by the API Apps. This was causing 405 errors when trying to call my API Apps.

The resolution for me was to adjust my web.config and turn OFF inheritance.

```
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <clear />
          <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```